# Custom calendar drag drop event: Find date dropped to

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I've been working in silverlight to do a date-oriented application. I started off with changing the calendar template to contain a listbox on every date, and I created a listbox containing simple items.

I implemented an easy drag drop on both those elements, so now I can drag from the listbox containing the items to the listbox on a date and have an event.

Downside is: In the event, I don't know which date it was dropped to.

How can I figure this out?

Please note: The date dropped to is not necessarily the date currently selected...

Comment: I think the drag drop implementation will have a significant impact on the answer.  Might be an idea for you to detail that implementation, there a multiple different ways you may have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, using a different drag drop implementation (http://silverlightdragdrop.codeplex.com/) got me to the date relatively easy:

`DateTime datetime = (DateTime)((DropTarget)sender).DataContext;`

All thanks for viewing and thinking...